# « Toutes des affaires secrètes » : nature, fonction (et donc orthographe) de « tout » ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, tout-tous

Dans une [séquence](https://youtu.be/89CAY3gTWCo) de film on entend un enfant dire :

> Le château fort qu'on va faire, là, les murs vont être large « comme
> ça »,
>  Il va être plus gros que ma maison, plus haut que les
> arbres,
>  Il va, il va être super impressionnant, il va n'en avoir juste
> « un » château fort comme ça,
>  Avec des tours, des créneaux, plein de
> décorations, des portes, des fenêtres,
>  **Toutes** des affaires secrètes,
> on va même pouvoir y manger dedans,
>  Il va avoir tout qu'est-ce
> qu'on pourra mettre,
>  Il va être vraiment super beau, comme tous
> les châteaux du Moyen Âge,
>  Super super beau.
>
> [ François « Les Lunettes » ds. la [*Guerre des tuques*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Guerre_des_tuques) (Mélançon,
> 1984) ]

Quelle est la nature et le fonction de **toutes** dans la séquence : s'agit-il d'un [déterminant](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2910) ou d'un [adverbe](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2907), d'un [pronom](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2911) ; comment fait-on pour le savoir, plus d'une analyse est-elle possible ; y a-t-il accord ou est-ce invariable et finalement comment l'orthographie-t-on ?

Comment: T'es vraiment sûr qu'il faut comprendre **toutes**  et pas **tout** ? Avec un quelconque accent québécois est-ce que **tout** ne se prononcerait pas [tut] que ce soit **toute** ou **tout** ?

Comment: @None Non, je ne suis pas sûr, c'est justement parce que ça se prononcerait peut-être souvent [tut] que mon hésitation est encore plus grande. Et l'analyse n'est pas mon fort non plus.

Comment: Parce que moi je comprends que le gamin veut dire **tout** mis pour "tout ça dont je viens de parler" et donc **tout** dans ce cas est un pronom indéfini.

Comment: @None Ça peut certainement être une réponse, ne pas hésiter à la verser. Je n'ai pas accès aux sous-titres, c'est moi fait cette retranscription. Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait un emploi spécial, simplement la prononciation est celle trouvée parfois au Québec. Donc le contexte grammatical et l'analyse peuvent probablement permettre de retracer de quel emploi il s'agit.

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi, c'est une façon raccourcie de dire

- *Ça va être tout* [tʊt] *des affaires secrètes*,

ce qui en français standard serait *Tout ça va être des affaires (choses) secrètes*.

Il s'agit donc de l'adverbe *tout* du français québécois familier.